# What is the role of autowire in spring core?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In spring when I declare a bean like this :

`<bean id="dao" class="com.gestion.banque.dao.BanqueDao"></bean>`

I found an attribute named autowire  `autowire="byType"` and it's values is `default` or `byType` or `byName`.

`<bean id="dao" class="com.gestion.banque.dao.BanqueDao" autowire="byType"></bean>`

I am confused about this :

1 -> Can you explain what is this attribute ?

2 -> What is the role of this attribute ?

3 -> What is the relation between `autowire` Attribute and `@Autowired` annotation ?

4 -> What is the defferences between there values ? example defferences between `ByName` && `byValue`.

Comment: @autowire means DI by constructor.

Answer (score 0):

(1-2) You use the **autowire** attribute of the  element to specify autowire mode for a bean definition.
(3) Autowiring with annotations
isn’t much different than using the autowire attribute in XML. But it does allow for
more fine-grained autowiring, where you can selectively annotate certain properties
for autowiring.

(4) **byType** - Autowiring by property name. Spring container looks at the properties of the beans on which autowire attribute is set to byName in the XML configuration file. It then tries to match and wire its properties with the beans defined by the same names in the configuration file.
**byType** - Autowiring by property datatype. Spring container looks at the properties of the beans on which autowire attribute is set to byType in the XML configuration file. It then tries to match and wire a property if its type matches with exactly one of the beans name in configuration file. If more than one such beans exists, a fatal exception is thrown.

For more information use [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/index.htm) or read Wall's '*Spring in Action*'

Answer (score 0):

The **@Autowired** annotation performs dependency autoinjection in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

All beans' properties which you not obviously set up in your property tag will be injected by one of attribute value strategy

- byName - inject by find bean with the same name/id
- byType - inject by find bean with the same type
- constructor - in this case injecting will be done by autowire constructors' parameters by looking for their type
- default/no - all beans' parameters should be obviously initialized